# When you pick up a gun do you get the entire kit of the deceased?

Tags: battlefield-3

When you pick up a weapon that is on the ground during BF3 multi-player, do you get the deceased's kit as well ?

Not sure, But I think I have noticed a different secondary weapon (pistol) after picking up another gun when i have run out of ammo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you get all dead players weapons and equipment

Source: Personal experience

Comment: Also possibly important to note, you only get their equipment, not their perks or their physical appearance. Which is why sometimes you see an assault character sniping and a sniper reviving people.

Comment: So if they've unlocked the MAV but you haven't you then get that too for the duration of your current life?

Comment: Yes, just like weapons you can't use, you can use equipment you can't equip. And unlike CoD, it will track kills made with these weapons, allowing you to rank up weapons before unlocking them.

Comment: Afer more "Testing" myself, I can confirm that you get the kit from a dead player, not just the primary weapon.

Comment: You also get the ammo that they were carrying. So if they were out or nearly out, that is what you will have. I accidentally picked up a teammate's kit, and found myself out of ammo in the primary and secondary weapons. I had exactly 1 rocket grenade and my knife.